# jquery code under hidden input field is not work when we get it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added the field and their jquery code to get the value for that field like

```
<input type='hidden' name="test" id="test" value="data=$('#response').val()">
```

I am getting that hidden field value in jquery and splitting it by '=' but when I alert the value it shows the `$('#response').val()` i am expecting it to return the value of the response field type.

var val = $("#test").val();
var arr1 = val.split('=');

alert(arr1[1]);

return =>  $('#response').val()

expected => value of responce field.

please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: _"i am expecting it to return the value of the response field type"_ - Why? The content of `.value` is just a string. Adding something that could be JS doesn't make it JS.

Comment: Why are you doing such thing ? try to think about another solution , you can not put js in your value.

Comment: Looks like you're getting confused with server side (eg php) processing)

Answer (score 0):

in the value attribute there will be no javascript executed, it just contains the value of the input, see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp or compare to onclick attribute for example. There might be some parsing with alert, but it´s general knowledge not to debug any js with alerts.

you can just set the value attribute with javascript though

below your relevant markup you could do:

```
$('#test').val( $('#response').val() ); // will set the value

var expected = $('#test').val(); // will output the desired value then
```